# Completion block return type not recognized

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, class-method

Im making my first completion block and for some reason its not recognizing the return type so I cant pass the value back to the method call.

Heres my header declaration

```
+(void)downloadVenues:(void (^)(NSArray *myVenues, NSError *error))block;
```

Heres my implementation

```
+(void)downloadVenues:(void (^)(NSArray *myVenues, NSError *error))block{


//download scenes
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Venues"];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    else {
        // We found messages!
        myVenues = objects;


        NSLog(@"Retrieved %lu messages", (unsigned long)[myVenues count]);




    }
}];
```

And heres calling it in another file

```
//download venues
[Venue downloadVenues:^(NSArray *myVenues, NSError *error){
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    else {

    NSLog(@"myObjects are: %@", myVenues);
    _venues = myVenues;

    [self loadAnnotations];

    }
}];
```

For some reason its not recognizing myVenues in the implementation.  Why and how do i fix this?  Thanks

Comment: firstly you are missing the cal of the completion block. secondly, what do you mean *"its not recognizing myVenues in the implementation"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is never calling the completion block.
Here's what you should do:

```
+(void)downloadVenues:(void (^)(NSArray *myVenues, NSError *error))block{


//download scenes
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Venues"];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        block(nil, error);
    }
    else {
        // We found messages!
        block(objects, nil);


        NSLog(@"Retrieved %lu messages", (unsigned long)[myVenues count]);




    }
}];
```